# mysql slave server getting stopped after each replication request from Master

Tags: replication, mysql-5.6

Basic master-slave MySQL configuration has been done on Windows machine. Master and slave servers are running on localhost with different ports.

Now when executing update or insert in master server, slave server getting stopped after that event. Once restarting slave server and check updates then update/insert is successfully executed in slave through replication setup.

What could be the possible root cause of this issue?

Log of show slave status\G :

```
 *************************** 1. row ***************************

Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
              Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
              Master_User: masteradmin
              Master_Port: 3307
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: USERMAC38-bin.000007
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 840
           Relay_Log_File: USERMAC38-relay-bin.000004
            Relay_Log_Pos: 290
    Relay_Master_Log_File: USERMAC38-bin.000007
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB:
      Replicate_Ignore_DB:
       Replicate_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Ignore_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error:
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 840
          Relay_Log_Space: 467
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File:
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File:
       Master_SSL_CA_Path:
          Master_SSL_Cert:
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 0
            Last_IO_Error:
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
           Last_SQL_Error:
Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
         Master_Server_Id: 1
              Master_UUID: 63ac2f83-44ac-11e5-bafe-d43d7e3ca358
         Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                SQL_Delay: 0
      SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
  Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
       Master_Retry_Count: 86400
              Master_Bind:
  Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
 Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
           Master_SSL_Crl:
       Master_SSL_Crlpath:
       Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
        Executed_Gtid_Set:
            Auto_Position: 0
```

Error log of slave before it got stopped :

```
'CHANGE MASTER TO executed'. Previous state master_host='127.0.0.1', master_port= 3307, master_log_file='USERMAC38-bin.000008', master_log_pos= 123, master_bind=''. New state master_host='127.0.0.1', master_port= 3307, master_log_file='USERMAC38-bin.000013 [truncated, 295 bytes total]
Storing MySQL user name or password information in the master.info repository is not secure and is therefore not recommended. Please see the MySQL Manual for more about this issue and possible alternatives.
Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'masteradmin@127.0.0.1:3307',replication started in log 'USERMAC38-bin.000013' at position 498
Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'USERMAC38-bin.000013' at position 498, relay log '.\USERMAC38-relay-bin.000001' position: 4
```

General log of slave before it got stopped :

```
150819 11:04:44    10 Query stop slave
150819 11:04:45     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:04:48     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:04:51     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
10 Query    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = '127.0.0.1' MASTER_USER = 'masteradmin' MASTER_PASSWORD = <secret> MASTER_PORT = 3307 MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'USERMAC38-bin.000013' MASTER_LOG_POS = 498
150819 11:04:54     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:04:55    10 Query start slave
11 Connect Out  masteradmin@127.0.0.1:3307
150819 11:04:57     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:00     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:02    10 Query show slave status
150819 11:05:03     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:06     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:09     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:12     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:15     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:18     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:21     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:24     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:27     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:30     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:33     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:37     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:40     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:43     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:46     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:49     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:52     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:55     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:05:58     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:06:01     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:06:04     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:06:07     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:06:10     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:06:13     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:06:16     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
150819 11:06:18    12 Query BEGIN
12 Query    COMMIT /* implicit, from Xid_log_event */
150819 11:06:19     8 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found issue with different MySQL server version. Master server was running on MySQL version 5.7.8 and slave MySQL version was 5.6.10.

Synced both Master and Slave versions to 5.6.26. Replication is working fine without slave server being stopped.